# How to use "in respective of" and how does it compare to "in terms of"?

Tags: differences, prepositions, false-friends

How to use the expression "in respective of" and how does it compare to "in terms of"?

What is their appropriate usage?

Comment: How to use "in respective of": _Don't._

Answer (score 2):

Do not use it. There is no such term.

The nearest correct term is

> **With respect to**
>
> With respect to Section 13 of the contract, my client would like to suggest a change.

To compare:

> **In terms of**
>
> In terms of enforceability, the contract is weak.

Comment: 119 results for [in respective of](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JBi_Va7fG-al8weK7oXQAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22in+respective+of%22&tbm=bks&start=30)

Comment: 45,100 Google hits for ["in respective of"](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=JBi_Va7fG-al8weK7oXQAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22in+respective+of%22&start=50)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A What is that suppose to prove? (142,000,000 Google hits for that exact phrase, including error.)

Comment: And I quote: "There is no such term", obviously there are people who are using this expression. As to why, that is another matter.